# How to get unicode U0022 value which is ( ") without getting this "\" in my response code

Tags: javascript, rest, unicode

I am passing this in my request body

```
 nominalData = nominalData+"{u0022+orgId\u0022:"+"\u0022"+c8d1516d-dd51-4708-ba0d-d476e992792a+"\u0022}
```

And I am getting this in my response,

```
["Nominal″:[{\"orgId\":″c8d1516d-dd51-4708-ba0d-d476e992792a″}]]
```

I need to get this value like this which should not come with "\".

e.g.

```
["Nominal" :[{"orgId":"9d7555c5-ffb4-4cc7-8e44-e43be11fd342"}]]
```

How can I get this value?

Comment: why are you passing `"\u0022"` to start?

Comment: pls rewrite it well, you forget some '+' "{"\u0022"+orgId+ "\u0022:"+"\u0022"+c8d1516d-dd51-4708-ba0d-d476e992792a+"\u0022"}"

Comment: `"{\u0022orgId\u0022:\u0022c8d1516d-dd51-4708-ba0d-d476e992792a\u0022}"`, or simpler: `'{"orgId":"c8d1516d-dd51-4708-ba0d-d476e992792a"}'`